# QCView inputKey responds to NO but crashes on YES

Tags: cocoa, boolean, quartz-composer

I have a QCView with a boolean input splitter in it. When I try and do `[qcview setValue:NO forInputKey:@"showCube"];` it works as expected and the input gets set to `NO`. However, When I try and do `[qcview setValue:YES forInputKey:@"showCube"];` I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I have tried using 1, YES, and TRUE and they all give the same error. Whet could be the issue causing this mysterious error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setValue:forInputKey:` expects `value` to be an object (not a scalar, which you're supplying).

Try

```
 [qcview setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forInputKey:@"showCube"];
```

or

```
 [qcview setValue:kCFBooleanTrue forInputKey:@"showCube"];
```

(A standalone scalar `NO` works in this case, since it evaluates to `0`, equivalent to `nil` in Objective-C, which, under some circumstances, can receive messages without exploding.  But really you should be using either the NSNumber constructor, or one of the Core Foundation constants.)

Comment: It Worked! Thanks so much for the explanation of why NO worked it makes sense now!